# (python 3) Path gets weirdly altered when drag & dropping file on script

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

I wrote a simple script that decodes and sorts my scans (`*.pdf`) into Sharepoint. Everything works on my home PC where I tested it, but on my work pc it doesn't want to work. I want to drag and drop the pdfs (multiple sometimes) onto the script.
I printed out the path the script gets when the drag and drop starts.
Example: `20 ENS 02 0052.pdf` turns into `207D51~1.PDF`
Because somehow drag and drop doesn't work on this pc I had to create a shortcut to the script and add 'python' before the text in the target of the shortcut. ( But it also wont work if I just pass the file in console as argument
My debug script:

```
import sys
from pathlib import Path
import os
file = os.path.basename(sys.argv[1])
print(file)
os.system('pause')
```

The part of the original script i can show:

```
import os
import sys
import getopt
import sqlite3
from pathlib import Path

for pdf in sys.argv[1:]:
    # extract filename and 
    file = os.path.basename(pdf)
    # remove extension from full path
    filename = file[:-4]
    print("File: ".format(file))
    print("Filename: ".format(filename))
    # just for debug script would continue here
    os.system("pause")
    exit()
```

I tried it using a test script for debugging and passing the file as argument in console instead of drag and drop, but the same error happens. Worked on my work pc (also newest working version of python3).

Comment: Those are just alternate names for the same files. It's an artifact of Windows and its heritage; some components force the DOS 8+3 filename convention which is still there under the hood.

Comment: @tripleee The problem is that I use the raw filename in the script and split off first 2 chars and use them and then the three next ones etc, and without the right filename it doesnt work. is there a way to disable this one?

Comment: My happy recommendation is always to get rid of Windows. Somewhat more seriously, I don't understand what you mean by splitting off characters from the start - why would you do that?

Comment: [1/2] Sure its very rough but i'll explain. I scan documents for my company on a xerox. (multiple folders worth per day). and the only way to get the scans onto my computer is via the E-Mail Scan Option. Each document is one pdf file and needs to be saved correctly in the folder structure, which would be: '.../<Manufacturer>-<Product>/<Document Number>-<Year>.pdf'. To avoid creating a new folder each time and maybe confusing the files, i wrote the program in batch (which worked perfectly with an outlook macro that pulled out the files and ran the batch file with them as args.)

Comment: [2/2] The Batch file would create folders for me on the fly and rename the files for me. I came up with a 'naming scheme' the batch file would 'interpret' for the scans on the xerox which is '<YEAR (2 chars)> <Abbreviation (3chars) Manufacturer> <Product identifier (2 chars)> <Product Number( ( 4chars) > (<Product Number>)...'. I just rewrote it in python because it was disgustingly hard to add new manufacturers and products to the sorting program. Very easy with a sqlite3-database. But somehow im stuck now. I coded it in batch at first because nothing else can be installed (java, c...)

Comment: Its company property sadly, I would love to just use linux.

Comment: I would love to send you the script but i think i'll have to edit it first to not accidentally publish company secrets. Can I pm you somehow @tripleee ?

Comment: There is no facility for that here. You can chat once you have enough reputation but it's public. It's better if you put everything in your question anyway (or ask a separate question if it's going too far off track for what you are asking here).